# Ajax Call in MVP asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, mvp

I am working on a small project with MVP implementation using Ajax, JQuery.

I implemented passive view MVP pattern and all presenters are connected from view by event handling.

The scenario is displaying a detail popup box from master list by clicking the link on master row.

I have to make an ajax call to display the detail list. Now my question is how can I make a call via Ajax from client side to invoke an event.

There are 2 scenarios in AJAX call that I know:

1. Call Page Method: In this, How can I call a page method (this is static by default) which internally invoke a event in presenter?   If I call a presenter method directly in my view then It is violating the MVP pattern.
2. Call Web Service: How can I call a Web Service (Where it should be created?) how the presenter handle this service?

I googled so many sites but I couldn't find a right answer to implement.

Please clarify my questions and thanks for your support.

Thanks
Kalyan P

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in an [MVP framework I built](http://nucleo.codeplex.com) was to use a web service, and that web service implements a presenter.  So you call the web service, the web service fires an event to the presenter, the presenter responds to the model, and the web service returns anything within the model.

> If I call a presenter method directly in my view then It is violating the MVP pattern.

It depends who you talk to; some are in favor of calling a method on the presenter, rather than using a view event ([Jeremy Miller blogged about this](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/06/04/build-your-own-cab-part-6-view-to-presenter-communication/), for one).